# Xaml win8 issue: ListView works at design time, not at run time

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml

I'm having trouble with a freshly created blank page in Xaml/win8.  Here is my code:

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage
    x:Name="pageRoot"
    x:Class="MyApp.Contents"
    DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyApp"
    xmlns:common="using:MyApp.Common"
    xmlns:data="using:MyApp.Data"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <!-- Collection of items displayed by this page -->
        <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="itemsViewSource"
        Source="{Binding Items}"
        d:Source="{Binding TestSource.Items, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=data:MyDataSource, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"/>
    </Page.Resources>

    <!-- Snip Grid and Back Button -->

        <ListView
            x:Name="itemListView"
            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsListView"
            AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
            TabIndex="1"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Margin="-10,-10,0,0"
            Padding="120,0,0,60"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}"
            IsSwipeEnabled="False"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"/>
```

And here is the C# which backs it (TestSource constructor):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    TestSource.Items.Add(new ExampleData(TestSource));
```

In the designer, **this works properly**.  I see a list of 20 ExampleData exactly as you expect.

However, when I run the app, nothing is displayed on the page.  None of the "ExampleData" items show up (even though I'm sure the "TestSource.Items" observable collection got properly filled.

I've mostly copy/pasted this binding example from the SplitView demo.  Does anyone see what's wrong?  =[

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source for the CollectionViewSource is pointed at Items, not TestSource.Items. Your design source is correct but when you are running it would be wrong. Should be:

```
 <CollectionViewSource
    x:Name="itemsViewSource"
    Source="{Binding TestSource.Items}"
    d:Source="{Binding TestSource.Items, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=data:MyDataSource, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"/>
```